# Extracting property from another javascript file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My config file is being generated as the following

```
angular.module('config', [])

.constant('AURL', "http://localhost:4001/AURL")

.constant('BURL', "http://localhost:8000/BURL/v1")

.constant('APP_ENV', "development")
;
```

I am doing the following to extract data

```
var configFile = $.getScript("../config.js", function(data) {
  console.log("IT is", data);
});
```

If I want to get value of BURL how I can do it?

Thank you for helping

Comment: There's an extra single quotation mark (`'`) in the `../config.js`.

Comment: @code thank you I removed it but can you help in how to extract url for BURL?

Comment: Is the value of that file fixed?

Comment: Yes it will fixed not dynamic you can solve it using javascript as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solves the problem!

Since `getScript` delivers a string, I'll just imagine that you already received the data. Check out this code:

```js
// In getScript() callback
const data = `angular.module('config', [])
  .constant('AURL', "http://localhost:4001/AURL")
  .constant('BURL', "http://localhost:8000/BURL/v1")
  .constant('APP_ENV', "development");`;

let burl = data.match(/(?<='BURL', ").+(?="\))/)[0]; // Regex solves the problem!! We have a lookbehind with the necessary data (including "BURL"), and some stuff to terminate
console.log(burl);
```